# How to delete a file containing dots and backslashes in Fedora 17

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm using Fedora 17 and I generated a folder named `.\data\` from code

How can I delete this file from the command line?

Comment: No idea why "off topic" has "tex" but no... "linux"... really?  Anyway `rm -rf ./data` with the understanding that it is irrevocably *gone*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use additional backslashes to escape the special characters: `\.\\data\\`.  Hence, you would use:

```
rm -rf \.\\data\\
```

Answer (score 2):

Screen each backslash with another backslash or just enclose the entire folder name in single quotes:

```
rm -r '.\data\'
```